# Cross platform way of testing whether a file is a directory

Tags: unix, posix, system-calls, dirent.h

Currently I have some code like (condensed and removed a bunch of error checking):

```
dp = readdir(dir);
if (dp->d_type == DT_DIR) {
}
```

This works swimmingly on my Linux machine.  However on another machine (looks like SunOS, sparc):

```
SunOS HOST 5.10 Generic_127127-11 sun4u sparc SUNW,Ultra-5_10
```

I get the following error at compile time:

```
error: structure has no member named `d_type'
error: `DT_DIR' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I thought the `dirent.h`  header was crossplatform (for POSIX machines).  Any suggestions.

Comment: When I see cross-platform, I tend to assume you mean Windows and possibly OS/2 as well.  :-)  The answer for just Posix is easy, and someone already gave it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ref http://www.nexenta.org/os/Porting_Codefixes:

> The struct dirent definition in solaris does not contain the `d_type` field. You would need to make the changes as follows

```
if (de->d_type == DT_DIR)
{
   return 0;
}
```

> changes to

```
struct stat s; /*include sys/stat.h if necessary */
..
..
stat(de->d_name, &s);
if (s.st_mode & S_IFDIR)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Since `stat` is also POSIX standard it should be more cross-platform. But you may want to use `if ((s.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)` to follow the standard.

Comment: Actually POSIX defines a macro for this: `if (S_ISDIR(s.st_mode))`.  Also of course you should check that `stat()` is successful first.

Comment: Note that fstatat (2) might be more preferable over stat (2), because `de->d_name` is relative to the opened directory.

Comment: I looked into using fstatat() and it requires a file descriptor to the directory being read.  That doesn't seem to be a reasonable solution.